# dgrid with select field

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I looked all over the web for this "simple" question with no answer!
how to embed a select input field into a dgrid like this example:
suppose we have this column:

```
editor({ 
                    label: "name", 
                    autoSave:true, 
                    field: "f_name", 
                    className: 'style4' 
            }, "text", "dblclick")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
"dgrid.editor({
                    field: 'state',
                    editorArgs: {store: stateStore, style: 'width:120px;', maxHeight: -1}
                }, dijit.form.Select)"
```

Here is the example: https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/test/GridFromHtml_Editors.html

Comment: thanks a lot, I found the answer on one of the other test files on the link.
thought I am wondering why this code is so hard to find on the net?
I tried so hard to find the answer until you helped me. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

the answer based on frederic answer:

```
editor({
    label: "subject",
    field: "subject",
    editorArgs: {
        style: "width:75px;",
        options: [
            {value: "true", label: "true"},
            {value: "false", label: "false"}
        ]
    }
}, Select, "dblclick")
```